# DualChannel binding over Federation Security

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, sts-securitytokenservice

We are running a set of WCF services over HTTPS and using the ws2007FederationHttpBinding binding to authenticate against a STS.

Now we need to add a dual/duplex service using the same authentication technique.
[Know Your Binding Options](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Know%20your%20binding%20options) states that only wsDualHttpBinding is available for duplex services. Can i use it together with my STS and if yes does somebody know how to configure it?

Answer (score -1):

No, and if outward facing, dual binding is generally a bad idea.
http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2010/2/12/abusing-wcf-to-perform-remote-port-scans.html
Know the risks...